# Multiple Colors in Odoo Tree View

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Good Day! I just want to have a multiple color in tree view in Odoo, This will show if a Record 
state == approved colors is blue
state == post colors is red

Right now I only have a one color in Approved State.
Many Thanks for the Help!!

Comment: If I want to do this on M2O field then how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hi dear please see this [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/stock/product_view.xml#L11) and use attribute **colors**

[link 2](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account_payment/account_payment_view.xml#L155)

**Example**

```
 <record id="view_model_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">model_tree</field>
                <field name="model">model name</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <tree colors="blue:state == 'draft';gray:state in ('cancel','done');black:state == 'open'" >
                        <field name="state"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </record>
```

**Now you can use in v10 and v11,**

```
<tree decoration-info="template_stage_id==eco_stage_id"> <field name="template_stage_id"/> <field name="eco_stage_id" /> 
</tree>
```

and you can use more attribute like :

```
**decoration-muted** 

**decoration-dange**
```

Comment: If I want to do this on M2O field then how to do that ?

Comment: now  you can use in v10 and v11, <tree decoration-info="template_stage_id==eco_stage_id">
                                    <field name="template_stage_id"/>
                                    <field name="eco_stage_id" />
                                </tree>
and you can use more attribute like : 
decoration-muted
decoration-danger

Answer (score 0):

### This will work, try this,

```
<tree colors="blue:state == 'approved';red:state == 'post'">
   <field name="state"/>
</tree>
```